# How to stroke an open path (vector)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, pen-tool

I'm on photoshop cs6

I am doing a vectorial drawing, i wanted to draw a path without closing it but that was impossible. If i don't close my path, it stays invisible

I tried to create a line then add an anchor point to it and move but for some reason it doesen't work like I wish :
[image]

thanks for the help

Comment: See relevant question - [Do paths in Adobe Photoshop have to be closed?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/do-paths-in-adobe-photoshop-have-to-be-closed)

Comment: To be honest, i didn't understand the response on this post :/

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate question. Are the answers in the linked thread not answering your question?

Comment: no it doesen't .... To start with, when i right click on the paths menu, i don't have the same options that the guy displayed in this link

Comment: See also https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/155791/359

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Draw your path with the tool mode set to "shape" and merely set the stroke options in the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen. This is possible in CS6 or newer with vector layers.

[image]

For versions prior to Photoshop CS6 you'll need to check here: [Do paths in Adobe Photoshop have to be closed?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/do-paths-in-adobe-photoshop-have-to-be-closed)

Comment: This actually worked like a charm :D. 
Plus, I never found this trick on the web. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this, and my personal preference, is to design your vector assets in Illustrator, and then paste/place them in your PSD as SmartObjects. Double click them in the layers panel to edit.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the path.  (press `A` and click the Path)
2. Click `edit` → `Define Custom Shape` (name your Shape)
3. Select "Custom Shape" from the `Tools` palette and select your newly created shape

Now you will be able to stroke your path easily